# Cartesian product on multiple pandas DataFrames at once

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to do in pandas an equivalent operation to MYSQL cartesian products.
For example table `a` and `b` have the same column name `"Price"`, I want to change the name as `"a.Price"` and `"b,Price"` and prevent those two `"Price"` attributes from merging into one column.

However, pandas merge can only merge two DataFrames on their shared columns:

```
dfa = pd.DataFrame({'price': [30,40],
                   'discount': ['0.1', '0.2']})

dfb = pd.DataFrame({'price': [100,120],
                   'title': ['abc', 'xyz']})

df_result = pd.merge(dfa,dfb,how="outer")

  discount  price title
0      0.1     30   NaN
1      0.2     40   NaN
2      NaN    100   abc
3      NaN    120   xyz
```

The result would be like this, but I want to rename these two `"Price"` attributes and separate them into two columns. *I saw other answers recommending to add the same keys to each DataFrame manually, but I want to know how to solve this problem when I have several large DataFrames (more than 2).*

Comment: It would be helpful to see how your select statement looks like.

Comment: Just like the normal SQL statement. Like "SELECT a.Price,c.title FROM a,b,c"

Comment: Please include an [**MCVE**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure why you might want to do this, but you could add a prefix to every column:

```
In [11]: dfa.add_prefix("a_")
Out[11]:
  a_discount  a_price
0        0.1       30
1        0.2       40
```

I would use [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) rather than `merge`:

```
In [12]: pd.concat([dfa.add_prefix("a_"), dfb.add_prefix("b_")])
Out[12]:
  a_discount  a_price  b_price b_title
0        0.1     30.0      NaN     NaN
1        0.2     40.0      NaN     NaN
0        NaN      NaN    100.0     abc
1        NaN      NaN    120.0     xyz
```

to do more than two, pass more into the list:

```
pd.concat([dfa.add_prefix("a_"), dfb.add_prefix("b_"), dfc.add_prefix("c_")])
```

Comment: Thanks. My data frames also do not have the indexes like yours [0,1]. There are no same keys between them, so can I still use concat() in this situation?

Comment: Yes you can! :)